# Dropdown list appearing behind widget. Fixable?

Tags: css, iframe, dropdown

I really hope I'm writing this in the right place, my apologies if not.   I recently changed my Wordpress theme and in doing so, one of the dropdown menu's which I had runnng perfectly on my old design is no longer displaying correctly.

On the following page there is a "Select by Country" search field.  The problem is, the dropdown menu isn't actually displaying as a dropdown - hard to describe but it almost looks like it is showing in an iframe.

https://www.escxtra.com

I have tried several CSS changes but nothing has fixed it. I'd really appreciate any help.

My coding for the form is as follows:
https://codeshare.io/ayrWmn

Answer (score 0):

You can position things in front and behind using `z-index` this CSS rule is determined by numbers and the highest number is in front. This is referred to as "stack order"

Apply a rule to both elements, the one you want in front do this: `z-index: 2;` and the one that you want behind it put `z-index: 1;`

You may not need to apply `z-index` to the one you want in the back. Negative numbers are allowed in this rule.

Learn more about `z-index` here: [w3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I have tried adding z-index as outlined but I still can't get the dropdown to appear in front of the widget that is situated underneath.   The only thing that seems to change things is adding an 'overflow' property - setting this to visible shows the dropdown but it looks somewhat transparent :(

Comment: @DannyNi please add a code snippet of the exact area that you face problems with, thanks.

Comment: @DannyNi Okay, I looked at your website and the country select, one of the `div`s wrapping your dropdown is actually prohibiting your dropdown from extending due to something along the lines of a fixed `height`. Check and see if any of the classes involved with the elements surrounding your dropdown have a specific value to `height` maybe include the CSS into that jsfiddle that is involved? Thanks! As for the transparency, check for opacity, your parent elements may be passing down to your dropdown.